# tap classname from parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to this technology, and this is my first project.

I am calling an API and receiving a big parsed JSON file. From that entire big JSON.text (which is HTML code inside JSON.TEXT), how can I tap a particular class from that text?

Here is a sample:

After parsing the JSON.text -  the outcome is -

some big html code then  `<table  class ="info">`  some big html code with TD and TR tag then `</table>` then again big HTML code.

I have to tap this table with `class="info"` from the entire parsed JSON.text which is HTML code.

screenshot  -

[image]

Comment: not sure why it coming like that. i paste the entire HTML code received from API call. it looks like  -  <cite class="citation web cs1"   and tag end after some text </Cite>

Comment: Please fix JSON in your question.  It is not coming out as JSON at all.

Comment: The `json.net` tag is for a .Net library for processing JSON. Not sure how that applies here.

Comment: Your sample doesn't look like JSON to me-- it appears to be HTML inside of a JavaScript string.  JSON and HTML are not the same thing.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: i already parsed the JSON, from "text" tag,big HTML code is there  where i have to tap . like -JSON.Text =  (some html code) then (<table class="info">  big html text</table> ) again (some html code).  now i have to tap this table class from that JSON HTML text.screenshot attached.

Comment: What do you mean with 'tap' ?

Comment: To fix the display issues in your question delete the symbols \`\`\`.

Comment: Don't post JSON as a picture. Copy paste the JSON in text format, and use the toolbar to format it as code.

Comment: Be aware that the image suggests that the `text` property is not a string, but an object with a `*` property, which is the text. Your question is really inaccurately phrased. You should edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
let response = {
    parse: {
        text: {
            "*": `<div><\/div>
            <p><\/p>
            <table class="infobox vcard"><\/table>`
        }
    }
};

let parser = new DOMParser();
// extract the text part and pass it to the parser
let doc = parser.parseFromString(response.parse.text["*"], "text/html");
// get the first table element from the DOM, and display its `class` attribute
let tab = doc.querySelector("table");
console.log(tab.className);  // infobox vcard
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you've got the HTML out of your JSON file into a string you have two options. Option 1 is a regular expression:

```js
// You have some string html
let match = html.match(/<table class="([^"])*"/)[1]
// match is the string "class1 class2" or whatever
match = match.split(" ")
// match is now an array ["class1", "class2"]
```

Option 2 is to find an HMTL parsing library (look one up), use it to parse the whole string, find the table using the output of that library, and extract its class that way.